# Behat - programatic test step definition (ArrayLoader)

Tags: php, bdd, behat, gherkin

I am successfully using Behat 3.0 with the tests defined in Feature files, using Gherkin language. However, in some cases, it would be useful to define the steps programatically - Gherkin is readable, but difficult to define multiple variants.

Is there a way to programatically define the test steps (in PHP classes), so these can be picked up by Behat? I have found `ArrayLoader` class, which seems to be able to do that. However, I wasn't able to make it working with Behat. It seems Behat is using Gherkin `FileLoader` by default and I haven't found a way to rewrite this behavior (or rather extend) in the config file.

How can I combine test input from Gherkin files with custom definitions specified in PHP files?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to programatically define the test steps (in PHP
>   classes),...

If I don't misunderstand what you want, you can do like this:

```
use Behat\Behat\Definition\Call\Then;
use Behat\Behat\Definition\Call\When;
use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext;

class FeatureContext extends MinkContext
{
    public function iWaitSeconds($second)
    {
        new Then(.....);
        new When(.....);
        new Given(.....);
    }
}
```

You need to do a bit of research for more examples.

e.g.: `new When("The content is:", new PyStringNode($string));`

Comment: That's not bad. I need something like DataProvider in PHPUnit: Define one method, but make Behat run it multiple times with different parameters.